# Turn String in to Date Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to turn a string containing unwanted text, a date, and an unwanted time in to an entry that contains only the date.

This is a sample of what I am starting with:

"Started: Sunday, October 30, 2016 3:17:37 PM"

And from that I would like to get:

"October 30, 2016"

I have tried to search the string for a comma using this code:

```
Dim fulldate As String, commaposition As Integer

fulldate = Cells(1, 1).Value
commaposition = InStr(fulldate, ",")

Cells(1, 2).Value = Right(fulldate, commaposition)
```

This however returns:

"2016 3:17:37 PM"

as it seems to pick the wrong comma.  I was hoping for the other comma, and then I could work on getting the time out, but alas I am stuck.

Maybe there is some basic function I am missing?  I understand looping and how to manipulate the code to work with multiple sets once I can figure the base out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Split function to separate Strings via a delimiter.

```
Dim fulldate As String

fulldate = Cells(1,1).Value
Cells(1, 2).Value = Split(fulldate,",")(1) & ", " & Left(Trim(Split(fulldate,",")(2)), 4)
```

Comment: This does exactly what I want.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Mid to get everything after the first comma.

`Cells(1, 2).Value = Mid(Cells(1, 1), commaposition + 2)`

Comment: Thank you very much for you help!